# Clojure doesn't work the way I want it to

Tags: clojure, readline

I made a function to take questions like this.

```
(defn ask-ques [ques pred]
  (print ques)
  (let [user-input (read-line)]
    (if #(pred user-input) user-input (recur ques pred))))
```

And I wrote main like this.

```
(defn -main []
  (loop []
      (let [user-input (ask-ques "CHOOSE ONE. (C)ontinue OR (E)xit : " #(contains? #{"C" "E"} %))]
        (when (= user-input "C") (apply body (rand-nth (seq voc-map))) (recur)))))
```

But, Clojure received the input first and printed "CHOOSE ONE. (C)ontinue OR (E)xit : " out, and pred does not work well.

What's the problem? Why does it work like this? And what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

`#(pred user-input)` is a function of zero arguments and, since it has a non-`nil` value, the `if` will treat it as truth, so you will always get `user-input` and it will never `recur`. I suspect you want `(pred user-input)` instead.

Comment: I wonder why read-line is executed before print in that code above additionally.

Comment: @SuhyeonCHOI you probably want to add `(flush)` call after the `print` call, because print doesn't automatically flush the output. Otherwise you can replace `print` with `println`, which does.

Comment: @leetwinski Thank you for letting me know. Thanks to your advice, my skills have improved.